# AxWindowsMediaPlayer, Volume change is not occuring while playing Midi File

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, midi, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am trying to change the volume of an `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` Object. Like this.

```
//Change Volume
private void VolumeTrackBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MidiAxWindowsMediaPlayer != null && VolumeTrackBar != null)
       MidiAxWindowsMediaPlayer.settings.volume = VolumeTrackBar.Value*10;
}
```

If I place a break point inside that `if` statement, I can see it is executed as I intended. 
But the volume change is not reflected during playback. It always plays at the same volume,no matter if I change the volume before, during or after.

The `TrackBar` has a range from 0 to 10, so when I multiply it's value by 10, I will always get something in the range 0-100, which is the range needed by the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and finding no solution (as well as other people having the same problem)
I found a fix.

Instead of referencing AxWMPLib, reference WMPLib

Then create the Media Player Object Like so

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer MidiWindowsMediaPlayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

This`Object` will allow volume changes to Midi Playback.

Answer (score 3):

u can use under code

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 100;
```

change code for your Request

Good Luck